# addition in javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, addition

i have this code to sum 3 numbers so i+j+k but I get as result Nan

here is the code:

```
var i = req.param('1', null);
      i = parseInt(i);
      var j = req.param('2', null);
          j = parseInt(j);

      var k = req.param('3', null);
         k = parseInt(k);

      var r = i+j+k;
      res.render('index', {result:r});
```

this is node based js

Comment: One or more of the three is not actually a number. Do a console.log on each one before calling `parseInt`

Comment: You should always pass a second argument `10` to `parseInt` to ensure it parses the number as a decimal value and not e.g. hex (0x prefix) or octal (leading zero)

Comment: Maybe you should declare your `r` variable before `i` (`var r = 0;`)and then instead of `parsetInt` into the same variable everytime, parse it to your `r` variable doing a sum like `r += parseInt(i)` and repeat that for `j` and `k`.. try that

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: *"...Maybe you should declare your `r` variable before `i`..."* Won't make any difference, see [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) (Although I always recommend doing all `var` statements at the top of the execution context, since that's where they happen anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.param('2', null)` returns `null` if the parameter is not specified.

You then call `parseInt(null)`, which gives `NaN`

If you add any number with `NaN`, you get `NaN`.

---

Use `req.param('2', 0)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You'll see `NaN` if any of the values in the calculation is `NaN`. In your example, presumably `i`, `j`, and/or `k` is `NaN`. You'll need to look to see which it is. Note that `parseInt` can return `NaN` (for instance, `parseInt(null)` is `NaN`).

---

Side note: It's almost always best to include the radix when using `parseInt`, e.g. `parseInt(i, 10)` rather than just `parseInt(i)`. That way, `parseInt` won't guess at the radix (number base).

Answer (score 1):

When JavaScript converts a string to an int using `parseInt`, it reads each character until it sees a non-numeric character.  A blank string (`''`) is non-numeric, so it gets converted to `NaN`.

Examples:

```
parseInt('ABC', 10); // NaN
parseInt('123ABC', 10); // 123
```

So, you need to make sure the input isn't blank; make sure it's actually a number.

P.S. I suggest adding the 2nd parameter to `parseInt`, it tells it what base to use.  If it's excluded, it tries to guess.  Sometimes this causes issues:

```
parseInt('12'); // 12 (base 10)
parseInt('012'); // 10 (the leading '0' makes it base 8 [octal])

parseInt('012', 10); // 12. forced to be base 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the three variables is NaN, then it's not adding, but concatenating. Do a console.log or alert for each variable to find the individual values to see which one isn't a number.

EDIT...oops, I just saw you are already forcing them to integers. which is good. So the error is actually happening at that step...one (or more) of your values is not a number and therefore can't be forced to an integer.